# Retrieving Results from Kernel

Tags: metal

I am experiencing some hiccups while playing around with the kernel function.

What I would like to do is simply send an array to the function and the get results back after `waitUntilCompleted` in an array.

The following is an array that will be filled with numbers from 0 to 123455 after `malloc` in a loop:

```
float *myVector = malloc(123456 * sizeof(float));
```

Here is the array, along with `myVector`, that will be sent to the kernel:

```
float *resultData =  malloc(123456 * sizeof(float));
id <MTLBuffer> inBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:&myVector[0] length:sizeof(myVector) options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
id <MTLBuffer> buffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:&resultData[0] length:sizeof(resultData) options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
```

Using compute command encoder, they are both set to be at index `0`, `1` with offset `0`, respectively.

The following sets up the sizes for thread group and threads within a group:

```
MTLSize threadGroupCounts = MTLSizeMake([device maxThreadsPerThreadgroup].width, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake((123456) / threadGroupCounts.width, 1, 1);

[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];

[commandEncoder endEncoding];
[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
```

I am getting twice the following error:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during
>   execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)

After having spent many hours on it, I came to the conclusion that the error is caused by the following lines:

```
MTLSize threadGroupCounts = MTLSizeMake([device maxThreadsPerThreadgroup].width, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake((123456) / [device maxThreadsPerThreadgroup].width, 1, 1);
```

If I set, just as an example, `(123456) / [device maxThreadsPerThreadgroup].width`to be `32`, the error would not occur but the results would be all zeroes except for the first 2 values within the array.

Here is how I try to get the results after processing:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer.contents length:sizeof(myVector) freeWhenDone:NO];
float *finalArray = malloc(sizeof(float) * 123456);
[data getBytes:&finalArray[0] length:sizeof(finalArray)];
```

---

Here is the function:

```
kernel void test(const device float *inVector [[buffer (0)]],
                 device float *outVector [[buffer (1)]],
                 uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    outVector[id] = -inVector[id]; 
}
```

I think I am having trouble with setting up the thread sizes. 
As a test, what I am trying to achieve is to set up the maximum threads per thread group allowed, dividing the size of the array by this number and send it off to process. Could someone show me how to set up thread group sizes, send an array to the function and eventually retrieve the results within an array correctly and properly?

Thanks.

Comment: There's an error with how you're computing the size of your `MTLBuffer`s. Because `myVector` is a pointer, `sizeof(myVector)` is probably 8, not 493824. That, in turn, causes you to not allocate enough space for your data, and to read beyond the bounds of the buffer in the kernel function. Try using the same size when creating the buffer as when allocating the float array with malloc, and see if that helps.

Comment: And you've also replaced the amount of data you copy out using `getBytes` with the correct count?

Comment: I think the way you're computing your threadgroup size and count is reasonable, though you should be aware of integer truncation. If the `maxThreadsPerThreadgroup` width hypothetically happened to be 128, the division for calculating the number of threadgroups would produce 964.5, which would be truncated to 964, causing the last 64 elements of the buffer not to be processed. If you need to compute on unusually-sized grids like this, it's often better to round the number of threadgroups you dispatch up and then protect against out-of-bounds accesses manually in the shader.

Comment: @warrenm Could you be so kind as to cite a simple example in your answer for what you have just mentioned regarding the remedy for guarding against elements not being processed by rounding up and the method to protect against out-of-bounds in the shader?

Comment: Done! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an error with how you're computing the size of your `MTLBuffer`s. Because `myVector` is a pointer, `sizeof(myVector)` is probably 8, not 493824. That, in turn, causes you to not allocate enough space for your data, and to read beyond the bounds of the buffer in the kernel function. Try using the same size when creating the buffer as when allocating the float array with `malloc`, and see if that helps.

You'll need to make a corresponding change to how many bytes you retrieve from the output buffer with `getBytes:length:`.

I think the way you're computing your threadgroup size and count is reasonable, though you should be aware of integer truncation. If the total number of elements to be processed isn't evenly divisible by the threadgroup size, the way you're computing the threadgroup count will round down, causing you to skip some elements.

One way to avoid this is to round up the number of threadgroups you dispatch instead, and explicitly check against the buffer length to prevent out-of-bounds accesses. So you'd compute your threadgroup count and size like this:

```
const int elementCount = 123456;
MTLSize threadgroupSize = MTLSizeMake([device maxThreadsPerThreadgroup].width, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadgroups = MTLSizeMake(ceil(elementCount / (float)threadgroupSize.width), 1, 1);
```

...pass in the buffer size like this:

```
[computeCommandEncoder setBytes:&elementCount length:sizeof(elementCount) atIndex:2];
```

...and check against the bounds like this:

```
kernel void test(const device float *inVector [[buffer (0)]],
                 device float *outVector [[buffer (1)]],
                 constant int &elementCount [[buffer (2)]],
                 uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (id < elementCount) {
        outVector[id] = -inVector[id];
    }
}
```